# "variable might not have been initialized" (in if statement).I have used switch statement followed by if. (JAVA)

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm doing a homework assignment to find the net pay of workers. I used a switch statement for workers of different skill levels to define their pay rates + plus to ask what deduction plans they want (they can have more than one). Then I ended the switch statement and used an if statement to calculate the total deductions. However i keep getting an error message for each of the deduction plans for example: (variable DenIns might not have been initialized) . I'm not sure what could be causing this. Would appreciate any help

```
Scanner read= new Scanner(System.in);
```

```
int skill, rate,MedIns, DisIns, DenIns;
double hours,regpay,overtime,totpay,totdeduct,netpay, ded1, ded2, ded3 ;

System.out.println("Enter your skill level.");
skill= read.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter hours worked.");
hours= read.nextInt();
switch (skill)
{ 
    case '1':
        rate = 30;
        regpay = 40 * rate;
        overtime = (hours - 40) * 1.5 * rate;
        totpay=regpay+ overtime; 
        break;
    case '2':
       rate=40;
       regpay= 40*rate;
       overtime=(hours-40)*1.5*rate;
       totpay=regpay+overtime;
       System.out.println("Enter 1 if you have medical insurance");
       MedIns=read.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter 1 if you have dental insurance");
       DenIns=read.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter 1 if you have disability insurance");
       DisIns=read.nextInt();
       break;
    case '3':
        rate=50;

       System.out.println("Enter 1 if you have medical insurance");
       MedIns=read.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter 1 if you have dental insurance");
       DenIns=read.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter 1 if you have disability insurance");
       DisIns=read.nextInt();

}


   regpay= 40*rate;
   overtime=(hours-40)*1.5*rate;
   totpay=regpay+overtime;
   if (MedIns == 1) {
            ded1 = 60;
        } 
   else {
            ded1 = 0;
        }
   if (DenIns == 1) {
            ded2 = 40;
        } 
   else {
            ded2 = 0;
        }
   if (DisIns == 2) {
            ded3 = 25;

        } 
   else {
            ded3 = 0;
        }

   totdeduct = ded1 + ded2 + ded3;




}
    }
```

Comment: This is because java has the rule to initialize local variables before accessing or using them. this is checked at compile time

Comment: so if i understand correctly, declaring the values of the variables within the switch statement wont intialise the variables?

Comment: You have three cases in your switch statement. And you don't have a default case (if so enters something else then 1, 2 or three). So it can happen the the value for MedIns will never be set in your code. So you should set all your variables to a default value when you create them. Otherwise you have to set all values in every case of your switch statement and also need a default case for your switch.

Comment: Also there is a missing break on case '3'. It's not the issue, but it's bad form. As the two others pointed out there is no guarantee any value gets set in the switch statement so you have to initialize them before if you want to access them later.

Answer (score 1):

You define a row of ints:

`int MedIns, DisIns, DenIns;`

These ints do not have a value yet, which is required for primitive values before you can use them.

Next you perform a switch where you in 2 cases set the values:

*simplified code for explainability*

```
switch (skill)
{ 
    case '1':
        // VALUES ARE NOT SET
        break;
    case '2':
       // here the values are assigned
       MedIns=read.nextInt();
       DenIns=read.nextInt();
       DisIns=read.nextInt();
       break;
    case '3':
       // here as well
       MedIns=read.nextInt();
       DenIns=read.nextInt();
       DisIns=read.nextInt();

}
```

Now in two cases the values are never assigned. Namely: `case '1'` and also when none of the cases are met (the `default`)

You can solve this in two ways:

**1. Initialize at the start:**

`int MedIns=0, DisIns=0, DenIns=0;`

This way they can never be not assigned, since you assign the values at the very beginning.

**2. Initialize in every case of the switch:**

```
switch (skill)
{ 
    case '1':
       MedIns=123
       DenIns=1234
       DisIns=12345
       break;
    case '2':
       // here the values are assigned
       MedIns=read.nextInt();
       DenIns=read.nextInt();
       DisIns=read.nextInt();
       break;
    case '3':
       // here as well
       MedIns=read.nextInt();
       DenIns=read.nextInt();
       DisIns=read.nextInt();
       break; // important, else this case will 'fall through' to the default block
    default: // will perform when skill matches none of the top cases
       MedIns=0;
       DenIns=0;
       DisIns=0;
}
```

Comment: hi there i really appreciate the help. I removed netpay but the errors persist. I did assign their values within the switch statement, why wont it work? And just to clarify, the errors are in MedIns, DenIns, DisIns. Many thanks.

Comment: @maryamp. edited the answer, I think this answers your question, let me know if you run into issues :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int DenIns=0;
```

initialize the variable to a starting value.